# Opencart filemanager doesn't work

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Opencart 2.0.1.1

Standart Image Manager isn't working.

When I choose some picture, it just opens in the browser, in console I have no errors. Any suggestions?(other functions don't work either, for example reload open image manager without css)
Please someone help)

Comment: have you modified `controller` or `.tpl` of `filemanager` ?

Comment: nope, other than that I restore them from a pure opencart 2.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

My js in .tpl doesn't work because my hosting turned on some plugin pagespeed that off scripts in views -_-

Solution:
Add this pagespeed_no_defer="" to script and it will work.

Comment: I am also trying to change the pagination in controllet/file manager.php from 16 to 36 and when I am running this then getting error unexpected Syntex class commonController in line 1 what may be the problem